# Why do we use G, H, and 'K' for groups?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, notation, soft-question

In many cases of mathematics, we tend to set several variables in ascending alphabetical order.

- $x,y,z \dots$ for normal variables
- $A,B,C\dots$ for sets, coefficients, matrices
- $V,W\dots$ for vector spaces
- ${I,J}\dots$ for indices, ideals
- $\mathcal{C,D}\dots$ for categories

But when we need 3 groups, we tend to use $G, H$ and suddenly, $K$, Which is unexpected.

Here are some examples that groups are denoted by $K$.

- [Prove that quotient group K/H is normal subgroup of quotient group G/H](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2583198/prove-that-quotient-group-k-h-is-normal-subgroup-of-quotient-group-g-h)
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_homomorphism#The_category_of_groups
- https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Pullback_of_Quotient_Group_Isomorphism_is_Subgroup

Why do we denote groups by $K$ regardless of the alphabetical order?

Comment: We don't, let  $X$ be a group.

Comment: I'm not sure there is a good reason. It's true that $I$ as a non-abelian group would feel "weird", but that's obviously just from habit. It's a self-sustained tradition.

Comment: Group, Gruppe...

Comment: If you call your group $I$ or $J$ you would probably want to call elements of those groups $i$ or $j$ which seems weird; I think because of their ubiquitous use as indices.

Comment: Your question contains an answer: $I,J$ are already reserved.

Comment: I would say using $G$ for the underlying set of a group is just tradition. Similar to how we use $V$  for a **V**ector space.

Comment: It seems Burnside's classic/ancient text used $I$ for a subgroup (for example, in his Theorem IV). He also used $H, K$ for subgroups, but I couldn't find any $J$'s. (Download his book from [here](http://www.gutenberg.org/files/40395/40395-pdf.pdf) (possibly this is the original 1897 version, it's not immediately clear) or view the 1955 reprint [here](https://archive.org/details/theorygroupsfin00burngoog/))

Comment: It can even be worse read Bertram Huppert, *Endliche Gruppen I* (in German) where groups are denoted by Gothic capitals and their elements by regular capitals; Walter Feit, *Characters of Finite Groups* does the same. So it runs like this: let $G \in \frak{G}$ and $H \in \frak{H}$ and $K \in \frak{K}$  be elements in subgroups ... arghhh!

Comment: @NickyHekster It would be consistent. Let $\mathfrak{G}$ be a Lie group with Lie algebra ${\rm Lie}(\mathfrak{G})=\mathfrak{g}$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Yes sure, and when I studied *Varieties of Groups* by Hanna Neumann, I needed to learn the Gothic alphabet ... all varieties are denoted as such.

Comment: Groups are sets, so capital letters fit for them. "Group" in most(ly spoken) languages starts with "G", so... Next ones in most(ly spoken) alphabets are "H", "I", "J", "K", but "I" and "J" are "booked" for other uses, as you pointed out, so as second and  third "best candidates" we are left with "H" and "K", respectively...

Answer (score 12):

These are choices that mathematical writers have to make. There's not enough letters for all the stuff we need them to represent, and they often clash. So nice clean alphabetic sequences reserved for special purposes sometimes get in the way of our notational needs.

The letters $I$ and $J$ are also very commonly used for intervals in the real line. In particular $I$ is often reserved for one very special interval, namely $I = [0,1] \subset \mathbb R$. It is even somewhat common to be writing about groups and intervals at the same time, for example when writing about the fundamental group $G = \pi_1(X)$ of a topological space $X$ in which the elements of the group are represented by certain continuous paths $f : I \to X$ where $I = [0,1]$.

So, due to its many other busy duties, to avoid clash of variables the letter $I$ is rarely used for groups.

And $J$ usually refuses to be used too, in protest of the insult to his buddy $I$.

On the other hand $K$ is happy to be used for a group, particularly as a normal subgroup of a group $G$, because in that case $K$ is the **K**ernel of the quotient homomorphism $G \mapsto G / K$. And we sometimes jump *wayyyyy* further in the alphabet just to use $Q = G / K$ for the **Q**uotient group.

Comment: "*...And **J** usually refuses to be used too, in protest of the insult to his buddy **I***." This is the humor I needed today!

Comment: While I don't bother about the usage of $I$ (and its buddy $J$) for *intervals* too much, as an algebraist I really want to reserve those for *ideals*. When I see $R/I$ or $A/J$, I assume it's a ring; when I see $G/K$ or $H/N$ I assume it's a group. If I meet $G/I$ or $R/H$, I would be momentarily confused.

Answer (score 5):

I think that $K$ is also used because of the German word *kompakt* for a compact group. Consider for example the [Iwasawa decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iwasawa_decomposition) of a group $G$, which is
$$G=KAN,$$
where $G$ is a connected semisimple real Lie group, $K$ a compact subgroup, $A$ an abelian subgroup and $N$ a nilpotent group. So $A$ for an abelian group is also customary, as is $N$ for a nilpotent group.

On the other hand, $H$ as a group notation doesn't rely on a property, but rather that we need *two* groups in general for a group homomorphism
$$
\phi\colon G\rightarrow H,
$$
and mathematicians then just proceeded alphabetically.